# Declaring an Atomic Iterator

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, iterator, atomic

Could you give me ideas about what would be the best way to iterate through an unordered_map in a multithreaded-setting, perform some operations on the map in each iteration in the thread function, and return back to main? I'm thinking of using an atomic unordered_map iterator in the caller function, however, I couldn't find much about this. I am new to multi-threading; so I get a bit confused about synchronizing threading and iterating.
Thank you!

Comment: Just break the problem into multiple ranges of iterators.  Give one thread one range, and then the next thread the next range an so on for the number of threads you want to have.  Then you don't need any synchronization between threads.  Synchronization is costly so you want to minimize it as much as you can.

Comment: You need to understand where the race conditions are in the stl code: deleting a node you are also accessing is a big no-no; Incrementing or finding an iterator while deleting or adding is also an issue. You can have lots of parallel readers no problem, but you need to decide how fine-grained you need the protections to be. Note that a container full of shared pointers helps a lot, as threads take a reference to the pointer to operate on, rather than relying on the lifetime of the iterator.

Comment: _perform some operations on the map_ Which operations? Suppose you will only work with node values, right?

Comment: In my map; the keys are strings, and the values are vectors of integers. I would be removing some integers from the vectors -- so the values would be modified.

Comment: Why do you have to modify the map while iterating over it concurrently?

Comment: It should be safe to modify the values, if, as @NathanOliver suggests, each thread operates on a separate subset of the map.

Comment: @GokceDilek Then, you can safely use the approach suggested by NathanOliver.

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't find how could I divide an unordered_map into ranges for different iterators? @NathanOliver

Comment: `auto it1 = um.begin(); auto end1 = std::next(it1, items_per_threads); auto it2 = end1; auto end2 = std::next(it2, items_per_threads); ...`Of course you would do this in a for loop though so you don't have to declare a bunch of variables.

Comment: Oh wow, that easy, I didn't know about ```std::next``` method! Thanks a lot! @NathanOliver